# What's the proper pronoun when performing an action in IRC?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, internet

In IRC chats you can "perform an action" with the /me command. It changes the way the text looks so that it's a little more third person and narrative. Here's an example:

```
chmullig: I'm really hungry
sam: You should eat some cake
chmullig: You're right, I should!
* chmullig eats some cake
```

However if we wanted to use a pronoun, what would it be? `chmullig eats his cake` or `chmullig eats my cake`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third person pronoun, `chmullig eats his cake`.  You're writing for how it will be viewed, basically.

Comment: "You're writing for how it will be viewed, basically." -- Good point. Thanks!